# String cannot be cast to java error

Tags: java, string, button, integer

MyButton4 does not work, output shows error,

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at knapsacproject.Interface.getTableData(Interface.java:198)

It's showing this line error,

> tableData[i] = (int) model.getValueAt (i,colIndex);

What is wrong ?

```
public int[] getTableData(DefaultTableModel model, Integer colIndex) {
    int nRow = model.getRowCount();
    int[] tableData = new int [nRow];

    for(int i = 0; i< nRow; i++) {
        tableData[i] = (int) model.getValueAt (i,colIndex);
    }
    return tableData;
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    int nRow = model.getRowCount();

    algorithm algo = new algorithm(getTableData(model, 1),getTableData(model, 2),
    Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()),Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText()),Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
    int[] result = algo.getResult();

    for(int i = 0; i < nRow; i++) {
        if(result[i]==1)
            model.setValueAt("take", i , 3);
        else
            model.setValueAt("leave", i, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: the error tells you cannot cast String to int. try Interger.parsetInt instead. BTW you could have just googled this one

Comment: please , check return type of model.getValueAt(...) ? it's looks like it returns String and you are attempt to cast it into Integer.

Comment: As a side note, Java classes are with capital letter. `algorithm` should be `Algorithm`.

Comment: Thank you, I answered below

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error as you are assigning string value into an int array.

You need to do `Integer.parseInt()` to convert string into int.

```
tableData[i] = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt (i,colIndex));
```

Comment: Thank you, I answered below

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse String into Integer using below code.

```
tableData[i] = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt (i,colIndex));
```

Comment: Thank you, I answered below

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the `String` value returned by the method `getValueAt (i,colIndex)` to `int` (which is not possible), so basically it gave you a `ClassCastException`

What you need is to convert that `String` value to an `Integer` value using one of the methods mentioned in the answers:

```
tableData[i] = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt (i,colIndex));
```

or

```
tableData[i] = Integer.valueOf(model.getValueAt (i,colIndex));
```